Failed to remote connect via JMX to embedded ActiveMQ Artemis
I am using embedded ActiveMQ Artemis 2.38.0 for testing. I created embedded ActiveMQ Artemis as follows:
Configuration mqConfig = new ConfigurationImpl();
server = new EmbeddedActiveMQ();
mqConfig.addAcceptorConfiguration("tcp", "tcp://127.0.0.1:61616");
mqConfig.setSecurityEnabled(false);
mqConfig.setJMXManagementEnabled(true);
mqConfig.setMessageCounterEnabled(true);
mqConfig.setMessageCounterSamplePeriod(500);
mqConfig.setMessageCounterMaxDayHistory(1);
server.setConfiguration(mqConfig);
server.start();

After creating this embedded server I created several queues. Then I use JMX remote access to get the Queue depth:
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(jmxUrl);
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
....

jmxUrl is service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi.
However, I got this error:
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]

I suspect that JMX is not running. I am stuck.
I want to use JMX to get queue depth for queues created on embedded ActiveMQ Artemis server in tests only.
This application is old Spring Boot application, I am trying to upgrade it to Spring Boot 3.x from Spring Boot 2.x, and Java from 11 to 17. This used to use embedded ActiveMQ Classic. It does not work with Spring Boot 3.x so I switch to embedded ActiveMQ Artemis.  Now the JMX does not work for this embedded ActiveMQ Artemis.
I searched all the examples in this https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis-examples/tree/main repo, but I could not find any examples for embedded ActiveMQ Artemis + JMX.
I do need an embedded ActiveMQ Artemis + JMX for tests.

Is the code that's trying to get the queue depth in the same JVM as the embedded broker? If so you can simply use the EmbeddedActiveMQ instance to get that information.

I see what you mean. but, getting the queue depth part is done in a library, parallel to IBM MQ, which is our production MQ and uses JMX to get the queue depth.  If possible, could you help me to get this work...  as EmbeddedActiveMQ is definitely started, and queues are created on it, and I see mbean reference in the log... Just somehow the JMX is not started for remote access....  I searched all the document, JMX configuration is in management.xml, however, I could not find a way to provided it when creating the EmbeddedActiveMQ, and I would like to turn off security for JMX as well.

The EmbeddedActiveMQ will not manage its own MBean server. However, you can create one yourself and pass it to EmbeddedActiveMQ using the setMbeanServer method. The broker will then take this MBean server and register all of its MBeans in it, e.g.:
MBeanServer mbeanServer = MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer();
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
JMXConnectorServer connectorServer = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi"), Map.of("jmx.remote.protocol.provider.pkgs", "javax.management.remote.rmi", "jmx.remote.server.default.class", "javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl"), mbeanServer);
connectorServer.start();

Configuration mqConfig = new ConfigurationImpl();
server = new EmbeddedActiveMQ();
// customize your EmbeddedActiveMQ here
server.setMbeanServer(mbeanServer);
server.start();

Then you can establish a JMX connection with a client URL like this:
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi

That said, if the code that's trying to get the queue depth in the same JVM as your EmbeddedActiveMQ then you can simply do something like this to get the depth of a queue named foo:
System.out.println("Queue depth for \"foo\": " + server.getActiveMQServer().locateQueue("foo").getMessageCount());


Thanks a lot, let me give it a try, I will report back!

the constructor of MBeanServerFactory is private: public class MBeanServerFactory {
/*
 * There are no instances of this class so don't generate the
 * default public constructor.
 */
private MBeanServerFactory() {

}


I updated my comment to address your issue.

Thanks, I tried with your adjusted comments, still the same thing, when trying to connect with JMX, I got Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]

A default MBeanServer will not accept remote JMX connections which is why you're seeing Connection refused. I added some code to enable basic remote connectivity. To be clear, this isn't a tutorial on how to configure an MBean server. There are other resources on the Internet for that. The real question here is how to integrate that MBean server with ActiveMQ Artemis and that's what I've demonstrated with the code in my answer.

After I created JMX server as in your solution, now it works, thanks a lot!
